# Android Studio: Unable to find explicit activity class but activity already declared in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-glide, staggered-gridview

New to Android Studio here.

I am trying to make it so when I click on an image from a ViewHolder in a RecyclerView, it would open up another activity that opens up another layout.

However, I am getting this error even though I already declared the activity in my Manifest.

The code that is trying to create an Intent to start a new activity is a class is called `StaggeredView` inside `app/core/StaggeredView`. While the activity handler is called `ImageView` inside `app/ImageView`.

**Error**

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.image_chan/android.widget.ImageView}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2065)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:675)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5278)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:662)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5664)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5617)
        at com.example.image_chan.core.StaggeredAdapter$1.onClick(StaggeredAdapter.java:63)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**Code**

**onBindViewHolder** (which overrides the function from `class StaggeredAdapter which extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StaggeredAdapter.ViewHolder>`)

```java
public class StaggeredAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StaggeredAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    /*...*/
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loader);

        Glide.with(Context)
                .load(urls.get(position))
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.name.setText("SCORE: " + imgNames.get(position));
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Context viewContext = (Context) view.getContext();

                Intent toView = new Intent(viewContext, ImageView.class);
                viewContext.startActivity(toView);
            }
        });
    }
    /*...*/
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.image_chan">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/netconfig"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Image_chan">
        <provider android:name=".core.Suggestions"
            android:authorities="com.example.image_chan.core.Suggestions"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Image_chan.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ImageView"
            android:label="image_chan"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Image_chan.NoActionBar">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="image_chan"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
     </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow these steps.

1.You should rename ImageView class to something else like ImageViewActivity or any thing.

2.Make sure this activity extends Activity or AppCompatActivity.

3.Make sure this activity is under directory app\src\main.

This should resolve your problem.

Comment: Why am I not free to choose the names of my activities? That sucks — especially since it worked for 15 years. (I'm spending all my time making useless changes just because Google changed stuff around.)